# can't open certain websites, using VPN or not

Tags: 14.04, vpn

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and Firefox, and even installed and tried Midori. When I try to open certain websites, by either clicking the link from a search engine, or directly typing the address into the address bar, I get the message "Unable to connect" It's usually government websites. I did some searching and found a solution requiring typing in some code, but it was for an older version of Ubuntu. I use PhantomPeer VPN, but I get the same trouble weather I'm using it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not every DNS servers keep themselves updated with localized domains such as government domains .
Change your DNS server to Google'S public DNS server by entering following IPs in your network manager

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```